# Is there some way to measure how much a result matches fulltext query?

Tags: mysql

I want to display a list of related products in my eshop.

The problem is that sometimes matches are to broad, is there a way to get a colum with a sort of grade to know how matchy the row is?

```
SELECT * FROM `Items` WHERE MATCH(`Title`,`Text`) AGAINST ('$allText')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work

```
SELECT *, MATCH(`Title`,`Text`) AGAINST ('$allText') as grade 
FROM `Items` WHERE MATCH(`Title`,`Text`) AGAINST ('$allText') 
ORDER BY grade DESC
```

Comment: how does that work? It's words count/matches or something like that? thanks

Comment: a similarity measure between the search string and the text in that row in the columns. Dont know exactly the algorithm but i believe its not simple as counting word or letter

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *, MATCH(`Title`,`Text`) AGAINST ('$allText') as score
FROM `Items` WHERE MATCH(`Title`,`Text`) AGAINST ('$allText') HAVING score>0.2
```

Like that you can limit the best result.